# Update dropdown after Items.Clear()

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I populate a dropdown with several items. When the user chooses one of these items, a second dropdown gets populated.

When the user clicks on the "x" button on the first dropdown, the two dropdown must be cleared. The first dropdown gets cleared automatically, and i clear the second dropdown by using "dropdown.Items.Clear()".

It happens that when i load again the data for the first dropdown, the second dropdown does not update.

This is the code:

```
protected void DropDownDiagStati_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedIndex = this.DropDownDiagStati.SelectedIndex;
        PopulateDDLStates(selectedIndex);
    }

private void PopulateDDLStates(int selectedIndex)
    {
        // Ottengo i diagrammi di stato in sessione
        ArrayList diagrammiStato = Session["stateDiagrams"] as ArrayList;

        if(selectedIndex > 0)
        {
            // Ottengo il diagramma di stato selezionato
            DocsPaWR.DiagrammaStato currDiagStato = (DocsPaWR.DiagrammaStato)diagrammiStato[selectedIndex - 1];

            // Ottengo gli stati del diagramma di stato selezionato
            Stato[] stati = currDiagStato.STATI;

            for(int i = 0; i < stati.Length; i++)
            {
                ListItem item = new ListItem();

                item.Value = Convert.ToString(stati[i].SYSTEM_ID);
                item.Text = stati[i].DESCRIZIONE;

                this.DropDownStati.Items.Add(item);
                this.UpPanelStatiDdl.Update();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.DropDownStati.Items.Clear();
            this.UpPanelStatiDdl.Update();
        }
    }
```

I see only the old value in the second dropdown and i cannot select it.

Comment: Did you set autopostback on true ?

Comment: On the first dropdown, yes, because it has the OnSelect.. listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the clear function removes also the default empty Item. I solved by creating a private method that removes all the items but the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove update pane or you can set data source to drop-down.

```
ddl1.datasource = DataSource;
ddl1.DataTextField = "name";
ddl1.DataValueField = "id";
ddl1.DataBind();
```